# Why datatable cant show data in React JS (axios)

Tags: reactjs, axios

I use axios to create my datatatable using MUIDataTable in my React JS. but with my code the result is just show empty table..

in code below i dont know where i should change, because the result is empty table without data result as in JSON.why const data cant be read, anyone can help?

here's my code

App.js

```
              import React,{Component} from "react";
              import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
              import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
              import axios from "axios";
              import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

              class App extends Component {
                // State will apply to the posts object which is set to loading by default
                constructor(props) {
                  super(props);

                this.state = {
                  data: [],
                  isLoading: true,
                  errors: null,
                };
              }

                // Now we're going to make a request for data using axios
                getData = async () => {
                  const option = {
                    url: "url/api",

                    method: 'POST',

                    data: {
                      "data": {
                        "name": "...",
                        "id":"..."
                    },
                    "encrypt": 0
                    }
                  };
                  axios(option)
                    .then(response => {
                      this.setState({
                        data: response.data.data,
                        isLoading: false,
                      });
                      console.log(response.data);
                    })
                    // If we catch any errors connecting, let's update accordingly
                    .catch(error => {
                      console.log(error.response);
                      this.setState({ error, isLoading: false })
                    }
                    );
                }

                // Let's our app know we're ready to render the data
                componentDidMount() {
                  this.getData();
                }


                // Putting that data to use

                render() {
                  const { isLoading, data } = this.state;
                  const columns = ["ID","Name];

                  const options = {
                    filterType: "dropdown",
                    responsive: "scroll",
                    selectableRows:false
                  };


             return (


                    <div>
                    <center><h3>List Data</h3></center><br/>

                      <MUIDataTable
                          columns={columns}
                          options={options}
                          data={data}
                    />

                    {!isLoading ? (
                    data.map(post => {
                      const {id, name} = post;

                      const data = [
                        [
                          {id},
                          {name}
                })
                ) : (
                  <p>Loading...</p>
                )}
                  </div>
                  );

                }
              }

              ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
              export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Your option is wrong. url should be outside of the option. the correct order is:
axios.post('url' , options , headers).This may be helpful.For more info please visit https://github.com/axios/axios.